# Combination of monolog telegram handlers

Tags: php, monolog

I have some issues to send log to two Telegram private channels.
I want to send "debug" and "info" messages to my channel "debug", and only "info" message to my channel "prod"

See my services.yaml file

```
services:
    telegramHandlerDebug:
        class: App\Formatter\TelegramHandler
        arguments:
            - '%env(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)%'
            - '%env(TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_DEBUG)%'
        calls:
        - method: setFormatter
          arguments:
            - '@telegramFormatter'

    telegramHandlerProd:
        class: App\Formatter\TelegramHandler
        arguments:
            - '%env(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)%'
            - '%env(TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_PROD)%'
        calls:
        - method: setFormatter
          arguments:
            - '@telegramFormatter'

    telegramFormatter:
        class: App\Formatter\TelegramFormatter
        arguments:
            $html: true
            $format: '%%message%%'
            $separator: ''
```

my monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
    channels: ['telegram']
    handlers:
        telegram:
            type: buffer
            channels: telegram
            handler: grouped_telegram

        grouped_telegram:
            type:    group
            members: [handler_telegram_debug, handler_telegram_prod]
            formatter: telegramFormatter

        handler_telegram_debug:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: debug
            level: debug
            channels: telegram
            handler: service_telegram_debug
        handler_telegram_prod:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: info
            level: info
            channels: telegram
            handler: service_telegram_prod

        service_telegram_debug:
            type: service
            id: telegramHandlerDebug
        service_telegram_prod:
            type: service
            id: telegramHandlerProd
```

and extract of my crontroller

```
   public function index(LoggerInterface $telegramLogger)
    {
        $telegramLogger->log('debug', 'Message type "debug" : channels debug');
        $telegramLogger->log('info', 'Message type "info" : channels debug + prod');
}
```

When i run my controller, i received the two messages in my two channels, without distinctions.
I'm not familiar with key "action_level" and "type:finger_crossed", maybe issue is here.